# Section heading overlap on div - CSS Styling

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone help me out on how to achieve the following shown below in red?

From what I understand it is a div overlap but I can't seem to figure out how to get it like this.

[image]

Comment: where is your code ? put it on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please include code with your questions. For the effect you are looking for explore negative margins or position properties.

Comment: I've added the code to the following jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rfnye87f/

Comment: i take it that's a button. there's no btn in the fiddle. which div is the grey background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below mentioned style to `.about-lower`

```
position: relative;
padding-top: 15px;
```

Remove `margin-top: 20px` and add the following style to `.lower-title-container`

```
position: absolute;
top: -26px;
left: 73px;
```

Updated JSFiddle link is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jwfcbsr3/1/).

Answer (score 1):

One method using `position: absolute`

I've adding padding to the container below to ensure it doesn't overlap with the button

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.header-img-container {
  background-image: url(../Images/about-header-img.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 330px;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.about-middle {
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.about-middle-text {
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.about-middle-text h2 {
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.about-middle-text p {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.about-lower {
  background-color: #FAF8F8;
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.lower-title-container {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

.lower-title {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #b2b0c5;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 22px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
}

.lower-title p {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.about-eagles-container {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.about-eagles {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.eagle-img-container {
  margin-right: 30px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.eagle-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.eagle-img-container:hover {
  background-color: rgba(225, 231, 242, 0.8);
}

.eagle-name {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-middle">
  <div class="about-middle-text">
    <h3>Rising Eagles</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, populo vocent perfecto has in, phaedrum aliquando omittantur mei in, evertitur intellegebat eum ut. Vel ea nulla mentitum. Id aeterno minimum sea, at est albucius scaevola consequat. Duo facer platonem expetendis eu, eu
      quando aliquip constituam sed. Ne invenire suavitate vulputate mei. Vestibulum mi sapien ac nunc vel. Pellentesque nec elit sit ac orci. Ut lectus venenatis eros diam, pellentesque natoque amet lectus felis, cursus laoreet blandit ut nulla vel libero.
      Venenatis tristique cras, ut vitae, lectus ornare enim, sapien luctus lacinia, aliquam nibh libero tincidunt ut. Commodo risus amet vivamus, molestie mattis at. Mauris massa, vitae dolor etiam sed. Sit mi dignissim elementum, sit nulla nec arcu
      in arcu, reprehenderit sem donec magna, nisl urna non, venenatis turpis risus duis ultrices. </p>


    <p> Vitae consul quodsi ea sea, ex graeci accusam copiosae sit. Ei error accumsan mel. Quo id populo melius ceteros. Ex per magna aliquam, eos scripta integre ex. Praesent in eu tincidunt. Commodo magni porta nonummy aliquam enim neque, dapibus phasellus
      sed volutpat, dui quam, parturient molestie ante massa bibendum. Pharetra in ut, aliquam pretium rutrum pretium luctus phasellus. Enim sem cras interdum, at dolor in.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="about-lower">
  <div class="lower-title-container">
    <div class="lower-title">
      <p>The Eagles</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Iterate over accounts and build div for each -->
  <div class="about-eagles-container">
    <div class="about-eagles">
      <div class="eagle-img-container">
        <!-- Change url to link to their personal page -->
        <a href="#"><img src="../Images/profile-img1.jpg" class="eagle-img"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="eagle-text">
        <p class="eagle-name">Charlie</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec no errem euismod ponderum. Pro no populo putant audire.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="about-eagles">
      <div class="eagle-img-container">
        <img src="../Images/profile-img2.jpg" class="eagle-img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<!-- i put the button above the first div -->
<input id="btn" type="button" value="the button"/>
<div class="about-middle">
```

css:

add

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
#btn {
    left: 75px;
    margin: -25px 0 0 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
}
.about-middle{
    border: solid 1px black; /* so it's visible. */
}
```

Comment: bare bones. hope i didn't dup ovokuro.